# Is it possible to create user interface with html, css, js in android app?

Tags: android, user-interface

I know there is WebView in android, but I do not want to display web page, but just create whole interface of mobile application with html, css and javascript.

I am web developer and i know these technologies most, so it would be great for me to create android UI with it.

I tried basic android views and layouts but i don't like them.

Comment: You might want to check into [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). It let's you create apps using HTML, CSS & JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called hybrid mobile development. You can use HTML, CSS and JavaScript to develop apps that works on several mobile OS (Android, iOS and -I guess- Windows Phone).
Do feel free to check PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com/).

It has advantages and disadvantages.

**Advantages:** Fast development, multiplatform.

**Disadvantages:** Performance (With native development you can take control of several features that varies from os to os), Debugging (You cannot debug as you would do with Android Studio or Xcode)